# psql: FATAL: "username" role not available

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying psql and getting an error.

```
$ psql
psql: FATAL: "myilmaz" role not available
```

Then I try

```
$ createdb python_getting_started
createdb: Unable to connect to template1 database: FATAL: "myilmaz" does not have access to the system
```

I run `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://$(whoami)` as indicated [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) and then started getting this error. I don't know if there was an error before that.

**Note:** I'm using Pardus 17.3, and it based Debian 9. 'myilmaz' is my username.

**Edit:** I tried adding my user to template1 in postgres user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These error messages do not appear in PostgreSQL; did you freely translate them from another language?

Anyway, your problem is likely that `psql` and `createdb` assume a database user name identical to your current operating system user name, which is `myilmaz`.

You can specify a database user name with the `-U` option.

But it is probably better to login as operating system user `postgres` and then run the commands, this is typically how PostgreSQL installations are set up.

Comment: Yes, my output is Turkish. I translated it.
I'm trying specify a database user name with the -U option. But I'm getting error:
```createdb python_getting_started -U postgres```
```createdb: template1 veritabanına bağlanılamadı: ÖLÜMCÜL:  "postgres" kullanıcısı için peer kimlik doğrulaması başarısız oldu 
```
Translate: ```createdb: Failed to connect to template1 database: FATAL: peer authentication failed for "postgres" user```

Comment: I tried switch user to postgres and change directory to my project. `Access Denied` and i tried with `sudo`. I create password from myilmaz. And i write my password in `postgres` user. But there is error. ```postgres sudoers dosyası içinde değil.  Bu olay rapor edilecek.``` **Translate:** ```postgres is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.```

Comment: Maybe you can become `postgres` with `sudo su - postgres`.

Comment: You should ask your system administrator how you can become user `root` or `postgres`. Otherwise you will never be able to administrate the database.

Comment: I am system administrator. I have both.

Comment: Then it is easy. As `root`, run `su - postgres`. Then try again.

Comment: I couldn't explain my distress. I give output: `myilmaz@pardus:~/Clouds/Dropbox/Heroku/python-getting-started$ sudo su `
`[sudo] password for myilmaz:`
`root@pardus:/home/myilmaz/Clouds/Dropbox/Heroku/python-getting-started# su - postgres`  
`postgres@pardus:~$ cd /home/myilmaz/Clouds/Dropbox               
-su: cd: /home/myilmaz/Clouds/Dropbox: Erişim engellendi `

Comment: Now I am thoroughly confused. I though you wanted to run `psql` or `createdb`, and now you try to `cd`... Where is the connection?

Comment: I ran `psql` and it was successful. I ran `creatdb` and it was not successful because `createdb: veritabanı yaratma başarısız oldu: HATA:  "postgres" veritabanı zaten mevcut`, Translate: `createdb: database creation failed: ERROR: "postgres" database already exists`. I can `cd` any directory without Dropbox directory. Then I move my project directory out Dropbox directory then I run `cretatedb`. I think it was successful. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error I solved by going to PostgreSQL and adding the DB name manually then npm start and everything ok now